# My local MySQL server starts via CMD, but won't start as a Windows service?

Tags: windows, command-line, mysql

When I start MySQLd via the command line, it starts perfectly fine and I'm able to run queries on the database:

```
C:\Users\Nicholas>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini"

(program is running)
```

However, the moment I try to start the program as a Windows service (whether in Task Manager or on the command line), the daemon instantly dies.

```
C:\Users\Nicholas>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MYSQL57

C:\Users\Nicholas>
```

I renamed my COMPUTER.err file and it does *not* generate any errors when it exits like this.

Does anyone know what could be preventing this from starting as a service?

Comment: Are you running as Administrator? "By default, only members of the local administrators group can start, stop, pause, resume, or restart a service. " https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes, I tried both a normal Command Prompt and then an Administrator Command Prompt and got the same result. Thanks for the question.

Comment: Even worse, now I can't even get it to boot up from the command line.

Comment: I had this issue, but when I checked the err file, it said 3306 was already taken.  I looked in the Task Manager and there was a mysqld running.  Must not have exited cleanly from the CMD and held onto the port.  Killing the process and trying to start the service again worked for me.

Comment: @ScottN The only way I was able to fix this was by doing a total reinstallation of Windows. Not much of a solution sadly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way I was able to fix this was to completely reinstall Windows sadly.